# How fix ChipGroup's direction when reCreate in a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-chips

There is a **ChipGroup** in a HorizontalScrollView. I'm creating chips programmatically.

[image]

When scroll fragment to bottom and ChipGroup off then scroll to top and it visible but ChipGroup's direction was change from ltr to rtl and vice versa and showed the latest Item chip but I want to keep the position constant for ChipGroup.

[image]

**How can fix this problem?**

This my xml code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_6x"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:id="@+id/hs_crypto_currency"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:id="@+id/chip_group_crypto_currency_category"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:singleSelection="true"
            app:singleLine="true"
            />

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "android:layoutDirection="rtl" to your HorizontalScrollView:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <HorizontalScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_6x"
      android:scrollbars="none"
      android:id="@+id/hs_crypto_currency"
      android:layoutDirection="rtl"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     >

      <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
          android:id="@+id/chip_group_crypto_currency_category"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          app:singleSelection="true"
          app:singleLine="true"
          />

  </HorizontalScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This solution is Ok when android:layoutDirection="ltr" and working, but It is not true for rtl direction, also default direction is rtl in my app.

Comment: You mean that when you use  android:layoutDirection="ltr" its working but  android:layoutDirection="rtl" not working?

Comment: exactly, my app supported two language: English and Persian. English language is ltr and everything is Ok but Persian language is rtl and it doesn't work true.

Comment: Sorry i don't know why when you add  android:layoutDirection="rtl" to HorizontalScrollView its not working